# How could we deal with more than 60 tags for Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: push-notification, tags, azure-notificationhub

We are implementing push notification for a football app.
According to Azure documentation, any registration or installation can only associate up to 60 tags.
We understand that is not the server limit. It is "per device per app" limit.

Suppose we would like to send any football event news to the users (e.g. red cards, score update) based on the matches (user preference), then 60 tags are not sufficient because there could be more than 100 matches per day.

For more examples, the tags may look like

- team1-team2-redcard
- team1-team2-score
- team1-team2-corner
- team2-team3-redcard
- team2-team3-score
- team2-team3-corner
  ...

So, how could we do to deal with the case that some users may potential subscribe to more than 60+ tags?

Comment: If we can tag the team instead of match, I think 60 tags could be okay. But the product owner prefer "match + event" user preference.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure Notification Hubs limits tags to 60. What we recommend to customers who need more than 60 tags is to store the device token in your backend along with any classification values, then build the audience on the backend and send notifications to all the devices that meet that criteria. That's the only way to do it.